# Could not load file or assembly after working on Unit Testing

Tags: c#, reference

I've been working on a project for a month now. I have even run the project this morning. I added a new Unit Test class to the test for the application. I was working on getting my test running along with a [TestInitialize] method and a [TestCleanup] method.

Now for some reason I am getting the following error on my project (not the test project):

> Could not load file or assembly 'SolidWorks.Interop.swconst,
> Version=28.1.0.74, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19f43e188e4269d8'
> or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> specified.    DispensingAddIn C:\Users\erics\source\repos\TestingEFClassLibrary\TestingEFClassLibrary\RegAsm

My Unit Test looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using Dispensing.Classes.Utilities;
using SolidWorks.Interop.swconst;

namespace TestEntityDB
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Summary description for SolidworksFeatureTreeTests
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class SolidworksFeatureTreeTests
    {
        public ISldWorks _swApp;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void StartTestEnvironment()
        {
            _swApp = new SldWorks();
            var errors = 0;
            var warnings = 0;
            _swApp.OpenDoc6(@"C:\Users\erics\Desktop\Part1.SLDPRT", 1, 1, "Default", ref errors, ref warnings);
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUpTestEnvironment()
        {
            _swApp.CloseAllDocuments(true);
            _swApp.ExitApp();
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var tree = new SwFeatureTree();
            tree.FeatureTreeConfiguration.ExclusionByNamesList.Add("(-) Sketch1");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, tree.FeatureTreeConfiguration.ExclusionByNamesList.Count);
            //tree.BuildTree(_swApp.ActiveDoc as IModelDoc2);
            //Assert.AreEqual(25, tree.TreeItems.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, Solidworks loads and runs just fine when run manually.

I have tried removing and readding the reference to SolidWorks.Interop.swconst in both the project and the testing project.

What could have happened here? How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to my problem and I'll document it here in case others might benefit from this.

My issue was I was using a NuGet package that required a version of SolidWorks.Interop.swconst version 28.1.0.74. When I added a reference to SolidWorks.Interop.swconst I selected the version that was installed with my latest version of Solidworks. Now the version of SolidWorks.Interop.swconst was actually newer than the version that was required by the NuGet package. Hence the error message.